# Windows scheduled task invoking powershell to call web method results in 401

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, iis, windows-task-scheduler

Testing this on my workstation.  Setting up a windows task that executes under my account.  The task simply calls a powershell script which has a call to a url inside.  The web app is running under windows auth, so shouldnt my credentials from the windows task be used to invoke the powershell script?  I am a local admin on my own workstation.

The powershell script is something like this:

```
# Setup reference to source folder, routes to api
$web = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$order_api = "http://localhost:57110/Home/ManualInventory"
$order_response = $web.DownloadString($order_api);
#  TEST
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

When I run the task, I get a http 401 error, as if the powershell script cant access the url.  Will I still need to use credentials within the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `Invoke-WebRequest` and passing default credentials through that. For example:

```
$request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:57110/Home/ManualInventory" -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Get
```

You can then access its content through `$request.Content`. I tested this on an internal website I have access to that requires windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting the web application within IIS you will need to apply your user credentials to the application pool for it to run as you might expect.